# Using Taxonomy Date Field as filter for view in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, view, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy term 'Round' to which I've added a date field that corresponds with the Sunday of each week in the list. I use this term in a content type for football matches which occur on Weekends. This allows me to add a number of football matches for any week listed in the taxonomy vocab.

For example, round 1 (term) is Sunday, 1st May (date field). So I add 4 football matches, choosing round 1 as the term for each. I don't have to add the same date for each match because it's already specified as a field in the taxonomy.

I'm creating a view to show the football matches for the upcoming weekend. The view has to display which round it is, the teams that are playing, and the date that it's being played. I've got it doing that fine, but it also has to filter on the date field in the taxonomy so that it only shows the upcoming round of matches, ignoring those matches which are in the past.

That's where I'm struggling. I've created a Taxonomy Terms on Node relationship, specifying the Rounds vocab. This allows me to select the date field as a filter, but it doesn't treat it as a date type (just treats it as a term/string), so I can't filter based on date.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer to this, and it was an oversight on my part. I hadn't enabled the views_date module, so although the view was recognising that it was a date for display purposes, it wasn't recognising it as a date for filtering purposes. Enabling that fixed the issue.